# How do I know what the camera is answered?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I start camera intent like this:

```
    public Intent openCamera(Context mContext) {
    File photoFile = null;
    cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(mContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(cameraIntent);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "CESTA: " + absolutePatch, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return cameraIntent;
}
```

I use `startActivity` because i can not use `startActivityForResult`

And i need catch camera result how do i it???

Comment: Why can't you use `startActivityForResult()`?

Comment: `How do I know what the camera is answered?` ... Can you translate this sentence in English?

Comment: You have to use `startActivityForResult()` to verify it

Answer (score 2):

You should start the activity with `startActivityForResult()`. In the activity that starts this activity to capture camera data, you should also implement the method `onActivityResult()`.

From the Google docs:

"When the startActivityForResult() method is executed, users see a camera application interface. After the user finishes taking a picture (or cancels the operation), the user interface returns to your application, and you must intercept the onActivityResult() method to receive the result of the intent and continue your application execution. For information on how to receive the completed intent, see Receiving camera intent result."

[Receiving camera intent result](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-receive)

[Here you go with the official docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

Comment: Im inside the object and on this place i need call onActivityForResult (this does not work)  or catch resul

Comment: I don't get your question. You start the camera intent with the intent you just created; so, for example, you should use 

`Intent cameraIntent = openCamera(this);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);


protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//HANDLE YOUR DATA
}`

Comment: I know it. But when I write mContext (this is the context in this object), so I have this option startActivity()                     I mean   mContext.startActivity(myintent)

Comment: I don't get your questions.

Comment: @LukášŠálek: You cannot get a result unless you use an `Activity` and `startActivityForResult()`. You will need to redesign your app to an `Activity` for taking the picture.